# WCF: How to design WcfServiceLibrary separately from main application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ipc, single-instance

I am somewhat new to WCF and I am running into a very simple design issue which I assume has well-established answers.  I created a (single-instance) main application that does all the 'business logic': connects to a database and a third-party API, executes admin user commands etc.  This application is meant to be run on a server machine, and my next step is to create a `WcfServiceLibrary` on top so that end-users can execute commands remotely using Wcf clients.

Logically the `WcfServiceLibrary` makes a reference to the main application assembly.  Call me naive but I thought this would let me access the main application objects and methods.  Well it does but by creating a duplicate of the main application within the `WcfServiceLibrary` process, which is a no-go.  (I also discovered that when accessed from within the WcfServiceLibrary a [single-instance application](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx) is being duplicated!)

How to resolve this issue?  So far I am thinking of the following:

- [Self-host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670896/exposing-a-winforms-application-internals-through-wcf) the Wcf service within the main application: possible but I would be losing the clean separation between 'business logic' and service logic
- Use IPC techniques to communicate between main application and `WcfSrviceLibrary`: this looks like an overkill as it creates another layer of server-client interface (except perhaps if I use out-of-process COM)
- Any other way?

Thanks in advance for your help!  I want to believe there's a simple solution to this problem round the corner...!

Comment: Extract all logic into separate assembly, reference this assembly from both your main application and your wcf service?

Comment: @Evk Such assembly would still be loaded twice: once for the main app running on the server, and a second (or more) time whenever the Wcf service is instantiated.  What I need is the Wcf service accessing the main app without duplicating it internally.

Comment: If you are on server, why you need some main app? Why not just use only wcf service?

Comment: The main app maintains a central database and an API connection with third-party software.  As I wrote it is possible to self-host the wcf service within the main app if there is no other option.

Answer (score 0):

This Might be what you are looking for ...

```
public static class RealAppCoreHelper
{
    private static RealAppCoreObject m_GlobalAppInstance = null;

    public static RealAppCoreObject GetGlobalMainInstance()
    {
        // return the one and only instance of our main app

        if (m_GlobalAppInstance == null)
        {
            m_GlobalAppInstance = new RealAppCoreObject();
        }

        return m_GlobalAppInstance;
    }
}
```

You could put this logic in the WCF wrapping app or your main app depending on the exact behavior you are looking for.

Comment: This would create a duplicate instance of the main app within the WcfServiceLibrary.  Remember that the main app is running on the server before the WcfServiceLibrary is called to host the service.